# Warning in PL/SQL after function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote a PL/SQL function that checks if a string is actually number or not, and the execution code. 
But when I excute the function, I get the follwing warning:

```
Warning: execution completed with warning
FUNCTION is_number Compiled.
13/1           PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN"
```

Here is my PL/SQL code with the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_number (p_string IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN INT
IS
   v_new_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
   v_new_num := TO_NUMBER(p_string);
   RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
   RETURN 0;
END is_number;

BEGIN 
  dbms_output.put_line(is_number('93')); 
END;
/
```

Normally, the console should return '1', but it doesn't.

Where is the error please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this line:

```
END is_number;
```

You should add a slash in order to execute the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

Without that, the parser continues to read the following lines as part of that statement, but since you have already ended the function, they are invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem is that you executed those two SEPARATE PL/SQL Blocks as a single statement.

Solution: execute them separately (add `/`)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_number (p_string IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN INT
IS
   v_new_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
   v_new_num := TO_NUMBER(p_string);
   RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
   RETURN 0;
END is_number;
/

BEGIN 
  dbms_output.put_line(is_number('93')); 
END;
/
```

This works perfectly fine:

[image]